# jQuery Mobile: page events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

Eu não consigo compreender muito bem a hierarquia dos *page events* do jQuery Mobile.

Como eu faço para montar todo o conteúdo de uma página HTML (e suas modificações) e somente apresentá-la para o *user end* quando a página estiver pronta?

Por exemplo: eu uso uma função JS para calcular as dimensões da screen para centralizar alguns elementos (horizontal e verticalmente), porém, quando acesso a página, os elementos aparecem no topo e são deslocados para o centro da página. Claro que isso é feito de forma rápida, mas é perceptível pelo usuário final.

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa que sempre deve ter em conta é ter no CSS tudo o que pode ter no CSS. Por exemplo, se quer esconder um elemento até a página carregar, então é melhor escondêr diretamente no CSS em vez de esconder no javascript e depois mostrar.

A sua pergunta não tem código e falta-lhe algum detalhe. Deixo aqui uma sugestão que é meio drástica, mas funciona.

Esconda o `<body>` no CSS e mostre depois quando a página tiver pronta.

CSS

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').show(); 
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/car8Z/)

Da mesma maneira que usei o `<body>` aqui (o que é meio drástico), pode usar em elementos mais específicos.
Tenho de deixar uma salvaguarda: em páginas onde o javascript está desativado, nada vai ser mostrado... mas e aí, hoje em dia, todas as páginas usam javascript.